# Como habilitar um botão após input ser preenchido

Tags: php, javascript

Estou precisando fazer com que um botão de "próximo" fique desabilitado enquanto o usuário não digitar dentro do input

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `jquery` para fazer isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#campo').on('input', function(){
    $('#manda').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length < 3);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Campo:</label>
    <input id="campo" type="text">
  <button id="manda" disabled>Mandar</button>
```

Agora ele irá fazer uma verificação, depois de 3 caracteres, ele troca a propriedade para diferente do valor que ele possui, no caso remove o `disabled` do `button` e você consegue prosseguir.

Comment: Tem a possibilidade desse botão só habilitar quando chegar a um número de caractere?

Comment: Pronto amigo, editei para mostrar que agora ele vai somente habilitar o campo, quando o usuário digitar mais do que 3 caracteres.

Comment: Sim, mas o menos trabalhoso é usar o jquery. Não sei, questão de praticidade e costume mesmo, minha opinião. Talvez trocando o precisa por "pode" melhore a minha colocação.

Comment: Pode substituir a condicional da prop por `$('#manda').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length > 3);` que vai funcionar igual, porém o código fica um pouco mais limpo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um evento que escuta quando algo é digitado no campo e habilitar/desabilitar o botão:

```js
document.body.querySelector("#texto").addEventListener("input", function(){
   
   var botao_proximo = document.body.querySelector("#proximo");
   
   // habilita o botão com 3 ou mais caracteres digitados
   botao_proximo.disabled = this.value.length >= 3 ? false : true;
   
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
<br>
<button id="proximo" type="button" disabled>Próximo</button>
```

> Se quiser que a ação ocorra após tirar o foco do campo, troque o
>   `"input"` por `"blur"`.